# i write a function that return list of all the owner address .but when i call the same function through web3 it will not show the same output

Tags: solidity, blockchain, ethereumjs

**This function return the All Nft Address**
*when i call this function from web3 it will return the same output that i will get from remix*

```
 function GetTotalNftAddress()
    public
    view
    returns (address[] memory)
{
    uint count; 
    uint256 total = totalSupply();
    address[] memory tokenIds = new address[](total);
    
    for (uint256 i=0; i < total; i++) {
            tokenIds[count] = ownerOf(i);
            count++;  
    }
       return tokenIds;
       
}
```

**this function returns the owner that is not a default Owner Address** *when i call this function from remix if will work fine and show the diff owner address the one i transfer the token but when i call this from web3 it with show the out of the above function*

```
function getTransferNftAddress()
    public
    view
    returns (address[] memory )
{
    uint count; 
//    uint getCount;
    uint256 total = totalSupply();
    address onwer = msg.sender;
    address[] memory token = new address[](getCounting());
       
    for (uint256 i=0; i < total; i++) {            
        if(ownerOf(i) != onwer){
          token[count] = ownerOf(i);   
          count++;   
        }

    }
    
    return token;
}
```

**The script i call**

```
    const Web3 = require("web3");

(async () => {
  const web3 = new Web3(
    "https://rinkeby.infura.io/v3/54864fd661734a288da4dcdda1ad2f7c"
  );
  
  const nftAddress = "0x11a5D56B034d0F3fFcEbCaa69bFE9Db526285d76";
  // ERC721 abi to interact with contract
    const nftBuild = (./build/Nft.json);

  // interact with contract
  const nftContract = new web3.eth.Contract(nftBuild, nftAddress);
  const getTransferNftAddress = await nftContract.methods.getTransferNftAddress().call()
    
  console.log(`Total NFTs Address: ${getTransferNftAddress}\n`)
  //console.log(`Total NFTs: ${total}\n`)

})();
```

Comment: Try setting from in the function call `nftContract.methods.getTransferNftAddress().call(from: "0x12341234..")`. When not specified web3 will use the zero address. My recommendation is to avoid using msg.sender in view functions for that reason, and instead pass the address as input parameter (also more flexible).

Comment: thanks thats solve my prob only if i have only getTransferNftAddress function in my contract . if i add the both function GetTotalNftAddress and getTransferNftAddress in my contract then the getTransferNftAddress function output will be the output of GetTotalNftAddress

Comment: I couldn't reproduce the issue with a test contract. I can suggest to verify the ABI and the contract address are the correct ones.